# Statistical significance of long term trend?

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, trend

I have data sets of long term climatology wind speed data on daily basis for  1950-2000.
I have calculated the mean for every year and calculated trend pattern, it shows some positive trend of 0.05 m/s/year.

I have been asked do the statistical significance test for this trend analysis.

How could I achieve it?

Comment: There are a variety of tests for trend ([e.g. read about trend here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trend_estimation)), depending what you assume about the circumstance where there's 'no trend'. You could, for example, look at the kendall correlation of average annual wind speed with year, but that would assume independence and no multiperiod cycles (aside from whatever the trend is supposed to identify), for example.

Comment: The related trend test to the Kendall correlation would be the Mann-Kendall test for trend, itself related to a Theil-Sen trend estimate. If you have correlation over time, or multi-year cycles, you'd need something else.

Comment: Some basic material is [here](http://www.iac.ethz.ch/edu/courses/master/electives/acwd/Trend.pdf) (also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trend_estimation)) and slightly less basic [here](http://pubs.usgs.gov/twri/twri4a3/pdf/chapter12.pdf); these would be good background.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help
Mann-Kendall test would be suitable i think.
What about seasonal kendal test will it be suitable if am doing decadal variability in wind speed or like any parameter???

Comment: shanas, I don't have enough domain knowledge relevant to your problem to say what's a suitable model. If you think that there's a cycle, you would want to adjust for it or use a procedure that allows for it.